# Where to "setPageSize()" in UiBinder for empty CellTable (GWT)?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I have a CellTable & a SimplePager. I want setPageSize(7) for that cellTable by default at the the time the Page got loaded.

In ui.xml file

```
<c:SimplePager ui:field="orderListSimplePager" pageSize="7"  />
<c:CellTable ui:field="orderListCellTable" />
```

in View.java

```
@Inject
public OrderManagementView(final Binder binder) {
    widget = binder.createAndBindUi(this);
    res.css().ensureInjected();
    orderListSimplePager.setDisplay(orderListCellTable);
}
```

After ran, nothing happened, the simple pager didn't take 7 as pageSize.

Now, i change the code a little bit by put `pageSize="7"` into `<c:CellTable>` in Ui.xml 
In ui.xml file

```
<c:SimplePager ui:field="orderListSimplePager"  />
<c:CellTable ui:field="orderListCellTable" pageSize="7" />
```

Now the above code is working if the CellTable already has data right at the first time the page got initialized. However, if the celltable has no data at the beginning, then it will display a loading message (see image) after initialising the page, which is not good:

[image]

Note: I want to setPageSize at ui.xml so i can change it easily.

So, Where to "setPageSize()" in UiBinder for empty CellTable (GWT)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change pagesize for everytime table loading.

But you can disable or change loading Indicator using this.

`celltable.setLoadingIndicator(new Label(""));`